# Discord.js Hoist role when created

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I hoist a role when it is created with discord.js?

My code : (not the entire code; just the code for creating the role)

```
message.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Admin',
    color: 'BLUE',
    permissions: [],
  },
  reason: 'Server setup.',
})
```

How do I hoist it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `.setHoist` Method, you can read the documentation on this here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setHoist

See the [Discord.js guide example](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setHoist):

```
// Set the hoist of the role
role.setHoist(true)
  .then(updated => console.log(`Role hoisted: ${updated.hoist}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Alternatively it may be possible to add `hoist:`  as an option, for example:

```
message.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Admin',
    color: 'BLUE',
    permissions: [],
    hoist: true,
  },
  reason: 'Server setup.',
});
```

However I have not tested this, but from my research I believe this should work.

Note: Answer Edited as it provided incorrect information.

Comment: Nope. I need to make it so the role created is separated from online members, which, according to my research, is called “hoisting”.

Comment: @John192 I have updated my answer to hopefully answer your question.